# How to push element in array of JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

This is my controller from which I am requesting to POST the data on server. While I am able to POST title and rating, i am unable to POST any genres because Genres is an array. How to push the data in Genres Array?

```
app.controller('addTrack', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.tracks = [];
        var genre = []; 
        var pushing =  genre.push($scope.add_genre);
        $scope.add_track = "";
        $http.get('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks?page=48')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.tracks = response.data.results;
            });
        $scope.add = function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $http.post('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks', {
                    title: $scope.add_title,
                    rating: $scope.add_rating,
                })
                    .then(function (data) {
                        $scope.genres = data;
                        //console.log($scope.add_genre);
                        $scope.add_title = '';
                        $scope.add_rating = '';
                        $scope.add_genre = '';
                    });
                $http.get('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks?page=48')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.genres = response.data.results;
                    });
            }
        } });
```

Http POST to http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks
Accepted response

```
{
    "title": "animals",
    "rating": 4.5,
    "genres": [
        1
    ]
}
```

Providing you my HTML as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="musicApp">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="addTrack">
        <div>
            <h1>Add New Track</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="add_title" placeholder="Type to add new Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Genre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="add_genre" placeholder="Type to add new Genre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Rating:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="add_rating" placeholder="Type to add new Rating" ng-keyup="add($event)">
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 bottom-button" value="click" id="button">Add a New Track</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label>Available Tracks</label>
            <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="track in tracks">
                <li class="list-group-item clearfix"><span class="pull-left title">{{track.title}}</span> <span class="genre">[{{track.genres[0].name}}]</span> <span class="pull-right rating">{{track.rating}}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all you need to declare `$scope.genres` in your controller, then with this code `$scope.genres = response.data.results;`, you are overriding the array, you need to use `.push()` like this: `$scope.genres.push(response.data.results);`, And I don't get it! A track should have only one `genre` isn't it?

Comment: @chsdk Haha I agree! The backend code has been quite vague that is provided to me. Can you help me with the code? I am unable to push the data to Genre Array.

Comment: Can you please explain better your scenario? Why would you use an array for genres? Shouldn't it be one genre per track?

Comment: Yes there should be only one Genre but in my task I have to add more than 1. My task is to add a track. In order to do that I need to add Title, Rating and Genre. So far, I have been able to add Title and Rating but I am unable to add Genre.

Comment: Then in that case you need to change your code to bind to atrack `object` and change its properties. I will try to provide an answer.

Comment: Surely please do that. I unable to do anything with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147115/discussion-between-prateek-gogia-and-chsdk).

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is to add a track object with `title`, `rating` and `genre`, you need to change your whole logic so your controller will bind all inputs to the same object properties.

First you need to define a `track` object in your controller, and bind the inputs to its properties in your HTML:

**JavaScript:**

```
app.controller('addTrack', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tracks = [];
  $scope.track = {
    title: '',
    rating: 0,
    genre: ''
  };
  $http.get('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks?page=48')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.tracks = response.data.results;
    });
  $scope.add = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $http.post('http://104.197.128.152:8000/v1/tracks', $scope.track)
        .then(function(data) {
          $scope.track = {};
        });
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="musicApp">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="addTrack">
    <div>
      <h1>Add New Track</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="track.title" placeholder="Type to add new Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Genre:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="track.genre" placeholder="Type to add new Genre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Rating:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="track.rating" placeholder="Type to add new Rating" ng-keyup="add($event)">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 bottom-button" value="click" id="button">Add a New Track</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:**

- Note the use of `ng-model="track.title"`, `ng-model="track.rating"`
  and `ng-model="track.genre"` in the HTML to bind these inputs to our
  `track`object properties.
- This code assumes that `genre` will be a string here, if you will use    a
  list of object you need to amend your code so it fits this option.

Comment: It still doesn't output anything in genre.